# State not updating as a plain value, but updates as a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I just get this situation, I'm using `react-use` [useKey](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useKey.md) hook and got a pretty weird behavior

The usage example of this hook is that:

```
import {useKey} from 'react-use';

const Demo = () => {
  const [count, set] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => set(count => ++count);
  useKey('ArrowUp', increment);

  return (
    <div>
      Press arrow up: {count}
    </div>
  );
};
```

As we can see it uses a function on the state update method `set`, but I found that too much and tried to made a simple change:

```
import {useKey} from 'react-use';

const Demo = () => {
  const [count, set] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => set(count + 1);
  useKey('ArrowUp', increment);

  return (
    <div>
      Press arrow up: {count}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The only change I've made was replacing that `count => ++count` with `count + 1`, but for some reason my change does not work, it acts like the new value of the state don't update on the `increment` function, but it does on the component.

Like, if I `console.log` on the component body it shows me `0` at first and then `1` after press *arrow up*, but if I press *arrow up* again the state does not update and if I try to log `count` inside the `increment` function it stills show 0.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on react when your state depends on old state value you must update it like this :

```
const increment = () => set(oldcount=>oldcount+ 1);
```

check [The React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) for more info

Comment: In the first example, the count is actually the oldcount, that's why it works. It's a bad practice to declare a new variable with the same name with old variable.